# Best way to add CSS to php files?

Tags: php, html, css

So I have some php code that uses the require function to help me make pages quickly. So the main .inc file is here. As you can see there is some html to add color and things like that. I want to add css now using a style sheet. Would I just add the style sheet syntax (.css) at the top of this file or the other files?

```
<?php
class Page
{
  // class Page's attributes
  public $content;
  public $title = 'TLA sdfds Pty Ltd';
  public $keywords = 'TLA Consulting, Three Letter Abbreviation, 
                   some of my best friends are search engines';
  public $buttons = array( 'Home'     => 'home.php', 
                        'Daily Specials'  => 'daily_special.php', 
                        'Car Wash' => 'car_wash.php', 
                        'Gas Station ' => 'gas_station.php',
                        'Deli ' => 'deli.php',

                      );

  // class Page's operations
  public function __set($name, $value)
  {
    $this->$name = $value;
  }

  public function Display()
  {
    echo "<html>\n<head>\n";
    $this -> DisplayTitle();
    $this -> DisplayKeywords();
    $this -> DisplayStyles();
    echo "</head>\n<body>\n";
    $this -> DisplayHeader();
    $this -> DisplayMenu($this->buttons);
    echo $this->content;
    $this -> DisplayFooter();
    echo "</body>\n</html>\n";
  }

  public function DisplayTitle()
  {
    echo '<title> '.$this->title.' </title>';
  }

  public function DisplayKeywords()
  {
    echo "<meta name=\"keywords\" content=\"$this->keywords\" />";
  }

  public function DisplayStyles(){
      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/app.css">';
  }

  public function DisplayHeader(){


}

  public function DisplayMenu($buttons)
  {
    echo "<table width='100%' bgcolor='white' cellpadding='4' 
                cellspacing='4'\n";
    echo "  <tr>\n";

    //calculate button size
    $width = 100/count($buttons);

    while (list($name, $url) = each($buttons))
    {
      $this -> DisplayButton($width, $name, $url, !$this->IsURLCurrentPage($url));
    }
    echo "  </tr>\n";
    echo "</table>\n";
  }

  public function IsURLCurrentPage($url)
  {
    if(strpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $url )==false)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  public function DisplayButton($width, $name, $url, $active = true){

    if ($active)
    {
      echo "<td width ='$width%'>
            <a href ='$url'>
            <a href ='$url'><span class='menu'>$name</span></a></td>";
    }  
    else
    {
      echo "<td width ='$width%'>
      <!-- this is where the side arrow goes on home page -->
            <img src ='side-logo.gif'>
            <span class='menu'>$name</span></td>";
    }  
  }

  public function DisplayFooter(){
?>
    <table width = "100%" bgcolor ="white" cellpadding ="12" border ="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p class="foot">&copy; TLA Consulting Pty Ltd.</p>
        <p class="foot">Please see our 
                      <a href ="">legal information page</a></p>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

<?php   
  }

}
```

// css file

```
h1 {
    color:red; font-size:24pt; text-align:center; 
    font-family:arial,sans-serif
}
.menu {
    color:red; font-size:12pt; text-align:center; 
    font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold
}



example of using require function:





<?php
require('page.inc');

class ServicesPage extends Page{
private $row2buttons =  array ('Re-engineering' => 'reengineering.php', 'Standards Compliance' => 'standards.php');



    public function Display(){
    echo "<html>\n<head>\n";
    $this -> DisplayTitle();
    $this -> DisplayKeywords();
    $this -> DisplayStyles();
    echo "</head>\n<body>\n";
    $this -> DisplayHeader();
    $this -> DisplayMenu($this->buttons);
    #$this -> DisplayMenu($this->row2buttons); #this line calls display menu a second time and creates a second menyu bar
    echo $this->content;
    $this -> DisplayFooter();
    echo "</body>\n</html>\n";
  }//end Display

} //end class page




    $services = new ServicesPage(); //create object
    $services-> content = '<p>This is the new page and it goes here </p>';

    $services->Display();

 echo "<body style='background-color:#F7F7F7'>";



?>
```

Comment: YOu need to insert the CSS correctly either as a link to the stylesheet within the `<head>` or inline (I'd recommend the first).

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" /> this way you can insert the css file link after <title> in the <head> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving methods out of a class to an include seems odd. Now when someone wants to update that class they have to go looking else where to do that. Also the fact that in that include you drop out of php `?>` will undoubtedly lead to some bugs down the road.

What you are doing to make the page less cluttered is a good idea but a better path might be removing that style tag and bringing in a style sheet.

So in `app.css` you would have:

```
h1 {
    color:white; font-size:24pt; text-align:center; 
    font-family:arial,sans-serif
}
.menu {
    color:white; font-size:12pt; text-align:center; 
    font-family:arial,sans-serif; font-weight:bold
}

/*ALL THE STYLES HERE*/
```

With that all you have to do now is

```
public function DisplayStyles() { 
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/app.css">';
}
```

Comment: So I did what you said by removing the style tag and adding a new file called app.css. However it still is not updating the colors. I will update my code

Comment: @j.doe.love I did not see that you were having issue with the styles being called in the question and the title does not point this out. Once you show your updated code I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, I would add a function "$this->addCss()" calling a function to pull your css into the head as the link it needs to be. With this method, you could add an argument to your addCss() method that would allow you to filter which css sheets to include based on some criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your DisplayHeader Function

```
public function DisplayHeader(){
   echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your css path">';
}
```